# Ruby modify hash value if value array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've got a ruby hash like this :

```
hash = {properties: [13], attributes: [11, 15, 15], places: [66]}
```

I want to convert my hash to this :

```
hash = {properties: 13, attributes: [11, 15], places: 66}
```

All values that have array lenght more than 1, keep them as they are (an array), all others first element. Tried this with couple of ifs, didn't turn out the way I wanted

```
hash.map{ |k,v| { k => v.uniq } }.reduce(&:merge)
```

Comment: What is the logic that converts `[11, 15, 15]` into `[11, 15]` for the key `:attributes`? You may have thought it is obvious from your code, but since you have not mentioned at all about that, it is not obvious.

Comment: @sawa I didn't say its obvious. I failed to mention that, my fault. The logic is to keep the unique numbers

Comment: When you have a question like @sawa's, reply with a comment if you wish, but please correct the statement of the question, as not everyone reads all the comments. Here I would suggest you identify an edit as such (with "Edit:" or somesuch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I'd do :

```
Hash[hash.map { |k ,v| [k, v.size > 1 ? v.uniq : v.first] }]
# => {:properties=>13, :attributes=>[11, 15], :places=>66}
# or 
hash.map { |k ,v| [k, v.size > 1 ? v.uniq : v.first] }.to_h
# => {:properties=>13, :attributes=>[11, 15], :places=>66}
```

Comment: What defines `to_h` for Array?

Comment: Ah, I'm using [2.0.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html), which apparently doesn't have it yet =)

Comment: I too thought `Array#to_h` was introduced in 2.0.0. (See, e.g., [this blog entry](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/).), but it's clearly [not there](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html). Both [Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) and [Enumerable#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) appeared in 2.1. @maerics, I suggest you upgrade to at least 2.1, as there were some problems with 2.0.0 (the "experimental" [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), for one).

Answer (score 2):

```ruby
def convert(h)
  Hash[h.map {|k,v| [k, v.size == 1 ? v.first : v.uniq]}]
end

convert(hash)
# => {:properties=>13, :attributes=>[11, 15], :places=>66}
```

Comment: Your answer is essentially the same as @Arup's earlier one, but as yours followed within nanoseconds, let's call it a tie. Plus 10 for both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
hash.merge(hash) { |*_, v| (v.size==1) ? v.first : v.uniq }
 => {:properties=>13, :attributes=>[11, 15], :places=>66}
```